# Invalid operand type error

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, nasm

NASM gives the following error message:

```
> ipl.asm:33: error: invalid operand type
```

Where the error appears:

```
    RESB    0x7dfe-$
```

Here is the code:

```
        ORG     0x7c00

        JMP     entry

entry:

        MOV     AX,0
        MOV     SS,AX
        MOV     SP,0x7c00
        MOV     DS,AX
        MOV     ES,AX

        MOV     SI,msg
putloop:

        MOV     AL,[SI]
        ADD     SI,1
        CMP     AL,0
        JE      fin
        MOV     AH,0x0e
        MOV     BX,15
        INT     0x10
        JMP     putloop
fin:

        HLT
        JMP     fin

msg:

        DB      0x0a, 0x0a
        DB      "hello, world"
        DB      0x0a
        DB      0

        RESB    0x7dfe-$

        DB      0x55, 0xaa
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *may* be because the operand for `resb` has to be a [critical expression](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.8). That means it has to be knowable on the first pass of the assembler <sup>(a)</sup>.

What you can do instead is to ensure you only use values already known in the first pass.

First, place a start label at 0x7c00:

```
          org 0x7c00
start:    jmp entry
```

Then change the space reservation to define another label and use the difference between them to calculate how many bytes are needed:

```
marker:   resb 0x1ffe-(marker-start)
```

What this does is calculate the number of bytes already output (`marker-start`, both values known before the `resb` statement) and subtract that from the number of bytes you wanted (`0x7dfe - 0x7c00 = 0x01fe`). Then it reserves that much space, as shown by the listing output:

```
0000039 00                       DB      0
000003A <res 000001C4>   marker: RESB    0x01fe-(marker-start)
        * warning: uninitialized space declared in .text section: zeroing
000001FE 55AA                    DB      0x55, 0xaa
```

You can see the final two bytes are at offset `0x01fe` which, given the `0x7c00` base, is actually `0x7dfe` as desired.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The reason why your expression is considered unknowable has to do, I think, with the fact that it uses an actual address, which is not necessarily known in pass 1. This is supported by the fact that `0xffff - start` will also cause the same error despite the fact it's using a real, already declared, label rather than `$`.

By instead using an expression like `0xffff - (label1 - label2)`, the labels themselves may not be known but the difference between them *is.*